# Support co-authoring with SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint

Can we support co-authoring with SharePoint list item? Simultaneously updating an item with 2 people in real time?

Answer (score 0):

You could enbale vesrsioning for the list in list versioning settings. So you could keep track of changes to list item through list item history.

[image]

[image]